# how to use the finished sorting function

Tags: javascript, css, json, ajax, sorting

I made a sort function in alphabetical order. I check her work through "console.log()". I sort of object. I have a question. how to make the function work when you select to "select>option". in "console.log()" it shows that the object is sorted. I want to when you select "select"> 'In alphabet order' blocks on the page rebuilt alphabetically. how to do it?

```js
function getData(url, callback) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      try {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        return;
      }
      callback(data);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

var results = [];
getData('https://api.randomuser.me/1.0/?results=50&nat=gb,us&inc=gender,name,location,email,phone,picture',
  function(data) {

    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data["results"].length; i++) {
      var fullName = data["results"][i]["name"]["title"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["first"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["last"],
        name = data["results"][i]["name"]["first"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["last"];
        img = data["results"][i]["picture"]["large"],
        imgM = data["results"][i]["picture"]["medium"];
      html += '<div class="col-md-2 block__user_on" onclick="myModal(this.id)" id="' + [i] + '"> ';
      html += '<img class="large" src="' + img + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
      html += '<img class="medium" id="medium" src="' + imgM + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
      html += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize name">' + name + '</p>';
      html += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize fullName">' + fullName + '</p>';
      html += '</div>'; 
    }
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = html;
    results = data["results"];

//SORT
    console.log( 
        results.sort(function (obj1, obj2){
            if (obj1.name.first < obj2.name.first) return -1;
            if (obj1.name.first > obj2.name.first) return 1;
            return 0;}
        )
    );

        }
    );

function imgMedium(){
    var large = document.getElementsByClassName("large");
    for (i = 0; i < large.length; i++) {
        large[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var medium = document.getElementsByClassName("medium");
    for (i = 0; i < medium.length; i++) {
        medium[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}

function fullName(){
    var name = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
    for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        name[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var fullName = document.getElementsByClassName("fullName");
    for (i = 0; i < fullName.length; i++) {
        fullName[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}


function myModal(index) {

    var data = results[index];
    document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";
    var modal = '',
        name = data.name.title + ' ' + data.name.first + ' ' + data.name.last,
        img = data.picture.large,
        street = data.location.street,
        state = data.location.state,
        email = data.email,
        phone = data.phone;

    modal += '<div > ';
    modal += '<img src="' + img + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
    modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize block__user_on_bold">' + name + '</p>';
    modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-street-view" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' ' + street + '</p>';
    modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' ' + state + '</p>';
    modal += '<p class="block__user_modal_email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' <a href="mailto:' + email + '"> ' + email + ' </a></p>';
    modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' <a href="tel:' + phone + '">'+ phone +'</a></p>';
    modal += '</div>';  

    document.getElementById("userModal").innerHTML = modal;

}
function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body{
    background: #eee;
}
a{
    color: #fff !important;
}
.block__user_on{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block__user_on:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f39c12;
}
.block__user{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.block__user_on-capitalize{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.block__user_on-capitalize:hover, .block__user_modal_email:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.block__user_on_bold{
    font-weight: 700;
}
.blok__user_background_modal{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.block__user_modal{
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    top: 10vh;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #708090;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
.block__user_modal_close{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.block__user_modal_close:hover{
   background: #eee;
   color: #000;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
.block__sort{
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.block__sort ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.block__sort ul li a{
    color: #000 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.block__sort ul li a:hover{
     border: 1px solid #f39c12;
}
.large, .name{
    display: block;
}
.medium, .fullName{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Api random</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container-fluid" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="block__sort">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Filter:</li>
                        <li><a onclick="imgMedium(this)">picture.medium</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="fullName(this)">name format</a></li>
                        <li><a onclick="reverseSort(this)">sort</a></li>
                        <li><select name="" id="">
                            <option disabled selected>order</option>
                            <option>In alphabet order</option>
                            <option onclick="reverseSort(this)">In reverse order</option>
                        </select></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="block__user" id="user">
                    </div>
                    <div class="block__user_modal" id="Modal">
                        <span class="block__user_modal_close" id="closeModal" onclick="closeModal(this)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <div id="userModal"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

or 
[at codepen](http://codepen.io/zaytsevav/pen/oBQrOm?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort handler should be moved to global scope and sort button should be able to call it on click. To render the content either on ajax load or on sort I moved the page render related actions under a function named 'renderResults'.

```js
function getData(url, callback) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      try {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message + " in " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        return;
      }
      callback(data);
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function renderResults(data) {

  var html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data["results"].length; i++) {
    var fullName = data["results"][i]["name"]["title"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["first"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["last"],
      name = data["results"][i]["name"]["first"] + ' ' + data["results"][i]["name"]["last"];
    img = data["results"][i]["picture"]["large"],
      imgM = data["results"][i]["picture"]["medium"];
    html += '<div class="col-md-2 block__user_on" onclick="myModal(this.id)" id="' + [i] + '"> ';
    html += '<img class="large" src="' + img + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
    html += '<img class="medium" id="medium" src="' + imgM + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
    html += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize name">' + name + '</p>';
    html += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize fullName">' + fullName + '</p>';
    html += '</div>';
  }
  document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = html;
  results = data["results"];

}

var results = [];
getData('https://api.randomuser.me/1.0/?results=50&nat=gb,us&inc=gender,name,location,email,phone,picture', renderResults);

//SORT
function sort() {
  var reverse = document.getElementById('order').selectedIndex == 2;
  results.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    var ret = 0;
    if (obj1.name.first < obj2.name.first) ret = -1;
    if (obj1.name.first > obj2.name.first) ret = 1;
    return ret * (reverse ? -1 : 1);
  });
  console.log(results);
  renderResults({
    results: results
  });
}

function imgMedium() {
  var large = document.getElementsByClassName("large");
  for (i = 0; i < large.length; i++) {
    large[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var medium = document.getElementsByClassName("medium");
  for (i = 0; i < medium.length; i++) {
    medium[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function fullName() {
  var name = document.getElementsByClassName("name");
  for (i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    name[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  var fullName = document.getElementsByClassName("fullName");
  for (i = 0; i < fullName.length; i++) {
    fullName[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}


function myModal(index) {

  var data = results[index];
  document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "block";
  var modal = '',
    name = data.name.title + ' ' + data.name.first + ' ' + data.name.last,
    img = data.picture.large,
    street = data.location.street,
    state = data.location.state,
    email = data.email,
    phone = data.phone;

  modal += '<div > ';
  modal += '<img src="' + img + '" title="' + name + '"/>';
  modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize block__user_on_bold">' + name + '</p>';
  modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-street-view" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' ' + street + '</p>';
  modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' ' + state + '</p>';
  modal += '<p class="block__user_modal_email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' <a href="mailto:' + email + '"> ' + email + ' </a></p>';
  modal += '<p class="block__user_on-capitalize"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ' <a href="tel:' + phone + '">' + phone + '</a></p>';
  modal += '</div>';

  document.getElementById("userModal").innerHTML = modal;

}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("Modal").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
}
a {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.block__user_on {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__user_on:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f39c12;
}
.block__user {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.block__user_on-capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
.block__user_on-capitalize:hover,
.block__user_modal_email:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__user_on_bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.blok__user_background_modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.block__user_modal {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 10vh;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #708090;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
.block__user_modal_close {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__user_modal_close:hover {
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.block__sort {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.block__sort ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.block__sort ul li a {
  color: #000 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.block__sort ul li a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f39c12;
}
.large,
.name {
  display: block;
}
.medium,
.fullName {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Api random</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="block__sort">
          <ul>
            <li>Filter:</li>
            <li><a onclick="imgMedium(this)">picture.medium</a>
            </li>
            <li><a onclick="fullName(this)">name format</a>
            </li>
            <li><a onclick="sort(this)">sort</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <select onchange="sort()" name="" id="order">
                <option disabled selected>order</option>
                <option>In alphabet order</option>
                <option>In reverse order</option>
              </select>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="block__user" id="user">
          </div>
          <div class="block__user_modal" id="Modal">
            <span class="block__user_modal_close" id="closeModal" onclick="closeModal(this)"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <div id="userModal"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. tell me how to hang 'onclick' on 'option' button without 'sort'?

Comment: Call the sort function on onchange handler of the select. Edited the answer to include this.

Comment: exactly, but I hung onclick. learn and study again. thank you so much